How to typeset commutative diagrams
I want to include the following commutative diagram in my work:

I tried using the following code:
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        \beta X \arrow[ld, "\pi_{\mathcal{F}}"] \arrow[d, "\pi_{\alpha}"] \arrow[rd, "\pi_{\mathcal{G}}"]\\
        e_{\mathcal{F}}X \arrow[r, "f"] & \alpha X \arrow[l, "g"] & e_{\mathcal{G}}X
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

However the output I ended up with looks something completely different:

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!
P.S. This is my first time posting here, so please forgive if there are any mistakes in asking the question.

Welcome. // Please start with a simple test: 1) copy your posted code into a new file; 2) compile it (it will fail); 3) add what's missing until it compiles; 4) replace your posted code with this compilable version. Thank you

BTW, I suspect you should add a & in front of your beta-line: placement is similar like writing to a table. This would position betaX over alphaX.

Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a "Minimal Working Example" (MWE) that starts with \documentclass, includes all relevant \usepackage commands, ends with \end{document} and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

There are some web frontends out there which can make producing these sorts of diagrams a bit easier (as long as you're not trying to do things that are too complicated). See for instance quiver or yichuanshen's app.

You're pretty close. Move \beta X to the second column by adding & in front of it. Then move your g arrow to the third cell in the row. Note that you can use ' to swap the side of the arrow where the label appears: \arrow[r, "f"']. You can alternatively use swap as an option: \arrow[r, "f", swap].

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}
       & \beta X \arrow[ld, "\pi_{\mathcal{F}}"'] \arrow[d, "\pi_{\alpha}"] \arrow[rd, "\pi_{\mathcal{G}}"]\\
        e_{\mathcal{F}}X \arrow[r, "f"'] & \alpha X & e_{\mathcal{G}}X \arrow[l, "g"]
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}


Just for completeness sake, a version using codi:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{concmath-otf}
\usepackage{commutative-diagrams}

\begin{document}
\begin{codi}
    \obj{
                                    &   \beta X     &                                \\
    | (eF X) | e_{\mathcal{F}}X     &   \alpha X    &   | (eG X) | e_{\mathcal{G}}X  \\
    };
    \mor [above]    (beta X)       "\pi_{\mathcal{F}}":->  (eF X);
    \mor            (beta X)  "\pi_{\mathcal{\alpha}}":->  (alpha X);
    \mor [above]    (beta X)       "\pi_{\mathcal{G}}":->  (eG X);
    \mor [below]    (eF X)    f:->     (alpha X)     g:<-  (eG X);
\end{codi}
\end{document}


Addendum:
You can load arrows from tikz-cd or define your own:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{concmath-otf}
\usepackage{commutative-diagrams}


\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\pgfqkeys{/codi/arrows}{
  ->/.style={/tikz/commutative diagrams/rightarrow},
  <-/.style={/tikz/commutative diagrams/leftarrow},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{codi}
    \obj{
                                    &   \beta X     &                                \\
    | (eF X) | e_{\mathcal{F}}X     &   \alpha X    &   | (eG X) | e_{\mathcal{G}}X  \\
    };
    \mor [above]    (beta X)       "\pi_{\mathcal{F}}":->  (eF X);
    \mor            (beta X)  "\pi_{\mathcal{\alpha}}":->  (alpha X);
    \mor [above]    (beta X)       "\pi_{\mathcal{G}}":->  (eG X);
    \mor [below]    (eF X)    f:->     (alpha X)     g:<-  (eG X);
\end{codi}
\end{document}



Very very nice. I not know of this package. +1 with all the hearth.

Is there a way to get arrow tips matching with Concrete Math?

Yes, you can load the arrows from tikz-cd or define your own.

For even more completeness, here's a version using xy
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,pdf,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
    \xymatrix{
    & \ar[dl]_{\pi_F} \beta X \ar[d]^{\pi_\alpha} \ar[dr]^{\pi_G} 
    \\
    e_F X \ar[r]_f & \alpha X & \ar[l]^g e_G X
    }
\]

\end{document}



We can use also xy package in a old version using typewriter package by @David Carlisle.
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{typewriter}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\let\Upsilon\relax
\let\Gamma\relax
\let\Delta\relax
\let\Theta\relax
\let\Lambda\relax
\let\Xi\relax
\let\Pi\relax
\let\Sigma\relax
\let\Phi\relax
\let\Psi\relax
\let\Omega\relax
\let\mathdollar\relax
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@R=2pc{
 & \beta X \ar[ld]_{\textup{\pi}_F} \ar[d]^{\pi_{\alpha}} \ar[rd]^{\textup{\pi}_{G}} & \\
e_{F}X \ar[r]_{f} & \alpha X & e_{G}X \ar[l]^{g}
}
\]
\end{document}



Oh, snap ... :-)
